# Strange behavior of the typeof operator and generics

Tags: typescript

Why are the types `o1` and `o2` counted differently?

```
type MyUnion = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type GenericData = { whatever: 'whatever' };
type FooData = { foo: 'foo' };
type BarData = { bar: 'bar' };
type BazData = { baz: 'baz' };

type MyData = {
    foo: FooData;
    bar: BarData;
    baz: BazData;
}

const builders = {
  foo: (_data: GenericData) => ({} as FooData),
  bar: (_data: GenericData) => ({} as BarData),
  baz: (_data: GenericData) => ({} as BazData),
};

type Returns = {
  [Prop in keyof typeof builders]: ReturnType<typeof builders[Prop]>;
};

type Builders = {
  [Prop in MyUnion]: (_data: GenericData) => Returns[Prop];
};

type Builders2 = {
  [Prop in MyUnion]: (typeof builders)[Prop];
};

declare const d: GenericData;

function fn<T extends MyUnion>() {
  const b1 = {} as Builders[T];
  const b2 = {} as Builders2[T];

  const o1 = b1(d);
      // ^? const o1: Returns[T]
  const o2 = b2(d);
      // ^? const o2: FooData | BarData | BazData
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFA5AM1VRygB9cAjAQwCdiycqAvHAbgCg3RIoBxCRCNWQBjACKVglLFADeUAO4ALCRABuggFy4lK9bSgBfdl2gAxQuMnS5BVFvyFiRzuGgAhGpanY5Vavb8nY1coD0YvaygmAMpmQ3YXbjgInzYodKhbLXNUL3YMqJotD2o8tIzo0Niygw5hdABnYCiAV2QAGwATQQbrcqyoAAoAfU6JSi0+ASExcYBKLAA+IZkDKEpenK85gBpyvy0RsclJ-kERbaWVtY2q0vm99Mqj8dPpi-mrwdX13rDtvbORLQABKEGALWoiF6qXSAG0AArUVBgKDIDAAawgIFQeCgJlxrQ63WoDQAulowRCoQAVVwAHgJePIbS6PURyLAZMW7CBJlCrJJMNk5Q5KLRGDgSDQiApQ1Gr14Zxml0wyypkOhYq5vIS-Lcgp6ACY+vCkeL0bAECh0HLBkyiWzSXNtWTdRxusJ2jRoPVoc1Om9zrNJAk8C1EMJgDLMoh6TSoBAAB7AfidXpSm2IRaDBYycp+ppRACM1huf0NpLhNLdBcazXIJp85YFxON1drdf9UFQpew5GLg06c3yBSgAHpx1AAHoAfi7RdQTaiRqHI-KBUnM-nBiAA)

Comment: The type of `o1` is generic because of [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), a PR specifically meant to allow this sort of "correlated" behavior across unions, meant as a way to handle [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). Before TS4.6 both `o1` and `o2` would be the same non-generic union type. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz
I think that completely. I don't have a better explanation. Please write an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before TypeScript 4.6, both `o1` and `o2` would have been the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `FooData | BarData | BazData`.  There was no support for [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (like `Builders`) with a [generic index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) (like `K extends MyUnion`) and getting a single function type we could call.  Instead, as soon as you tried to call the function, the index would widen to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) (so `K` turns into `MyUnion`) and then you just get a union return type instead of instead of a generic return type.  Most attempts to try to model a map of functions of different but related types would fail.  You'd want the function return type to be related to the input generic type, but it wouldn't happen.

TypeScript 4.6 introduced some fixes implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to help with such correlations.  This was specifically meant to deal with *correlated union types* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  I won't go into that issue much but it's related.

One of the implemented fixes allowed the compiler to "see" the correlation as long as the mapped type into which you are indexing is written explicitly where the property is a single function type.  This is the case for `Builders`, which is `{[K in MyUnion]: (data: GenericData) => Returns[K]}`, so `Builders[K]` is now transformed to `(data: GenericData) => Returns[K]`, and then everything proceeds nicely, where you can call the function and get `Returns[K]`.

But for `Builders2`, which is `{[K in MyUnion]: (typeof builders)[K]}`, that's not the case.  The compiler can transform `Builders2[K]` to `(typeof builders[K])`, but `builders` is not written explicitly as a mapped type over `MyUnion`.  It's a single object type with three properties each of which looks similar, of the form `(data: GenericData) => ???`.  But the compiler cannot "see" that as a single *generic* function call type; the best it can do is merge them together as a union and you get `(data: GenericData) => FooData | BarData | BazData`.  Oops.

So that's the difference.

---

Note that this has little or nothing to do with `typeof`, you can write a "good" version using `typeof`:

```
const returns: Returns = {
  foo: { foo: "foo" },
  bar: { bar: "bar" },
  baz: { baz: "baz" }
}
type Builders3 = { [K in MyUnion]:
  (data: GenericData) => (typeof returns)[K]
}
function fn<K extends MyUnion>() {
  const b3 = {} as Builders3[K]
  const o3 = b3(d);
  //    ^?const o3: Returns[K]
}
```

and a "bad" version without it:

```
interface _Builders4 {
  foo(data: GenericData): FooData;
  bar(data: GenericData): BarData;
  baz(data: GenericData): BazData;
}
type Builders4 = { [K in MyUnion]: _Builders4[K] }

function fn<K extends MyUnion>() {    
  const b4 = {} as Builders4[K]
  const o4 = b4(d);
  //    ^?const o4: FooData | BarData | BazData
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFA5AM1VRygB9cAjAQwCdiycqAvHAbgCg3RIoBxCRCNWQBjACKVglLFADeUAO4ALCRABuggFy4lK9bSgBfdl2gAxQuMnS5BVFvyFiRzuGgAhGpanY5Vavb8nY1coD0YvaygmAMpmQ3YXbjgInzYoKFstc1QvdnS-LQ9qXLSo2MLYkoMOYXQAZ2AogFdkABsAE0E661LMqAAKAH12iUotPgEhMVGASiwAPgGZAyhKbuyvGYAaUoKB4dHx-kERTYWllbXQz1md-PL9kckjydPZ8-7l1e6wzZ3nRLQABKEGATWoiG6qXSAG0AArUVBgKDIDAAawgIFQeCgJmxzTanWodQAuloQWCIQAVVwAHjxOPILQ6XXhiLAJPm7ABJlCzKJUNkpTZSJRGDgSDQiDJj0OvGOUzOmEWFPBkJFHO5CUBfMJXQATD1YQjRajYAgUOgZf0GQSWcSZhqSVqavVGtRQWq6uTPRDBTJeoQtDYg1AAES2MOGO5lfyyWNaMN+KMGGPRePppOxFNsaq8tz8roAZkiMIA0mLzZKrRpSv0nmN5a9ppI5sqBraPZTIY6yyTcxxUcBBHhKMJoIMC3riQAWIXpWz1uUTE4tygzLIWUZ5WNL55N1ebCrFbe7WJ7xsrxWzCrhU95kJT+11Oc+KDlysSy3SrSTwuz8sSUMDhOmEVoaGgWpIUadoXkPU82DwJpEGEYApQyRBaQrCAAA9h0Qdpui-KV5n6OYA3SKCGiiABGaxLh+f86kAncqMachDR8BjdWffUWI4Si3SgVA6OwcgaPrGYdwAemk9J0gAPQAflKNjhM4qJ9UkmS5Pk5SBKgNTyBLLjvh4gUi0A1ShNQEyoiLbTSlk+SoGUtTbJ9btmL7AyjNfWRuKfAUZyswToOE-zyBnRz0mcvSlPcmdNxyUZSGuE8rDIX5RlzIA)